# Ionic 3: Deeplink in Social sharing not working

Tags: ionic3, deeplink, socialshare

The scenario is I have to share the link of an app using social sharing. So I implemented a deep link of ionic. If I check through code pen it works fine.
i.e mydemoapp://home. But this is sent as plain text. So instead of URL scheme I user universal link i.e. https://mydemoapp.com/home. It is working fine in all sharing app like Whatsapp, text message, mail, etc. But If I used same it redirects to the browser and gives me the message 'Webpage not available'.

Does anyone have an idea how to share app link via facebook?

1.this.socialSharing.share('test', nul,nulll, ' https://mydemoapp.com/hom').then(res => { }, err => { });

2.this.socialSharing.share('test', null,null, 'mydemoapp://Home').then(res => { }, err => { });

## 1 is working with all sharing option but for facebook not

Plugin that I installed is ionic cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-deeplinks --variable URL_SCHEME=mydemoapp --variable DEEPLINK_SCHEME=https --variable DEEPLINK_HOST=mydemoapp.com --variable ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX=/

Comment: It would be great if you can share us some relevant code that you already have. This way, your code is less abstract and more comprehensible.

Comment: 1.this.socialSharing.share('test', nul,nulll, ' https://mydemoapp.com/hom').then(res => { }, err => { });
 
2.this.socialSharing.share('test', null,null, 'mydemoapp://Home').then(res => { }, err => { });

#1 is working with all sharing option but for facebook not

Comment: You can edit your question and put your code in there.

Comment: i have similar problem.. the link appear in sms or whatsapp or anything as plaintext can't click on it. so it will never redirect me to the app. in codepen work fine. should i configure appLinks on android ? because as i understand on android no need to do that

Comment: Yes, we can configure, but for that, we have to use universal link i.e, Deeplink_scheme://Deeplink_host/<your route>.  
e.g., (' https://mydemoapp.com/hom')
But for Facebook, it doesn't work.